# How do I hyperlink a button in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm currently working on an app using `swiftUI`. In the app, I wanted to add a link to youtube but I can't seem to.

```
Button(action: {
    //Set hyperlink to www.youtube.com
}) {
    Text("Go to youtube")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
Button(action: {

    if let yourURL = URL(string: "www.youtube.com") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(yourURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }

}) {
   Text("Go to youtube")
}
```

Comment: I get an error in the debug center...Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "invalid input parameters" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=invalid input parameters, _LSLine=252, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:options:completionHandler:]}

Comment: just add https://  then it will work.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the same, but, to make it work you have to use https://

```
Button(action: {

    if let yourURL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(yourURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }

}) {
   Text("Go to youtube")
}
```